# 音声再生時のエラー

Tags: swift

sample.mp3というデータを再生しようとするときに「引数が足りない」というエラーがでてしまいます。もしご存知の方は、ご指摘いただけますようお願いします。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sound_data = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound_data, error: nil)//ここでエラーがでてしまいます。
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Comment: `error: nil` の部分ですが、ここはオブジェクトへのポインタを指定するのではないでしょうか？ 例えば `var err: NSError?` としておいて、`error: &err` とするなどです。なお、`AVAudioPlayer()` の実行の後にエラーチェックをしておくと良いかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2から`try`, `catch`, `throw`という新しい構文が導入され、エラー処理の仕組みが大きく変わりました。

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508

同時に`NSError`のダブルポインタを取るメソッドは自動的に`throws`に変換されるようになったので、`NSError`の引数は無くなりました。変わりに、`try`を付けてメソッドを呼び出す必要があります。

```
let sound_data = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "mp3")!)
do {
    let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound_data)
    audioPlayer.play()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます。実行をしてみると、do{ の行でエラーが出てしまします。「statements are not allowed at the top level」というエラーです。こちらもswiftのバージョンアップによるものでしょうか？

Comment: viewDidLoad の中に書かないとダメですよ。

Comment: 大変ありがとうございます。音声再生のコードは完成したのですが、やはり再生をすると、音が流れません。新たに質問を載せませしたので、もしご指摘の点がありましたら、よろしお願いいたします。